# Redshift query hangs forever and PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, amazon-redshift

I was using IntelliJ Ultimate to query Redshift, as well as to debug some python code which was doing a simple one-row insert into Redshift.  Normally, the insert statement finishes in less than a second, but it started to hang.  It seemed that the query was waiting on a lock held by another query.

I used these queries (among others) to see what was going on:

```
select t."table", l.*, q.*
from stv_locks l
join svv_table_info t on (l.table_id = t.table_id)
join stl_query q on (l.lock_owner = q.xid)

select * from stv_inflight;

select * from stv_sessions;
```

And I discovered that a previous run of my python code in the debugger was still holding a write lock, even after the process had exited.  I determined that the problematic pid was 30461, so I tried to kill the session with:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(30461);
```

However, that didn't seem to have any effect whatsoever. Referring to [Amazon's documentation for pg_terminate_backend](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND.html), I also tried using the CANCEL command on the problematic statement:

```
cancel 1311;
```

IntelliJ didn't seem to be sending this statement to the server when I attempted to execute, so I had use the psql command line tool.  After executing, the problem still existed and despite much googling I was unable to find an answer.  It appeared that I might have to restart the Redshift instance to release the lock.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, it turns out, was to restart my IDE. Even after I tried disconnecting from Redshift in the IntelliJ database console, it seems to have persisted the connection that was causing the issue.  Immediately after I exited the IDE, The lock was released as I verified with the query:

```
select * from stv_locks
```